# ArcObjects snipped to Select all Features currently visible on the ArcMap screen (ActiveView)

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, features, select

I guess I have to get the extent of the ActiveView and then use it to perform a spatial search.

Is that the proper way to do it?

Please share the code snipped if you have any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. Not sure if I should use mxDoc.ActiveView instead of mxDoc.FocusMap.

```
        IMxDocument mxDoc = ArcMap.Document;
        m_focusMap = mxDoc.FocusMap as IActiveView;

        //Search geometry
        IEnvelope envelope = m_focusMap.Extent;

        IFeatureLayer featureLayer;
        IFeatureSelection featSel;

        //I want to get all features in the current extent of my ArcMap's FocusMap.             

        // 1. Loop through the layers in the map and add them to the selection            
        for (int i = 0; i < m_focusMap.FocusMap.LayerCount; i++)
        {
            if (m_focusMap.FocusMap.get_Layer(i) is IFeatureSelection)
            {
                featureLayer = m_focusMap.FocusMap.get_Layer(i) as IFeatureLayer;
                if (featureLayer == null)
                    break;

                featSel = featureLayer as IFeatureSelection;

                IFeatureClass featureClass = featureLayer.FeatureClass;
                System.String shapeFieldName = featureClass.ShapeFieldName;

                // 2. Create a new spatial filter and use the new envelope as the geometry
                ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = new SpatialFilterClass();
                spatialFilter.Geometry = envelope;
                spatialFilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelEnvelopeIntersects;
                spatialFilter.set_OutputSpatialReference(shapeFieldName, m_focusMap.FocusMap.SpatialReference);
                spatialFilter.GeometryField = shapeFieldName;

                // 3. Do the search
                IFeatureCursor featureCursor = featureClass.Search(spatialFilter, false);
                //featureCursors.Add(featureLayer.Name, featureCursor);

                #region  4. Do the selection
                // Invalidate only the selection cache. Flag the original selection
                m_focusMap.PartialRefresh(ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGeoSelection, null, null);

                IFeature feature = null;
                try
                {
                    while ((feature = featureCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
                    {                            
                        featSel.Add(feature);
                    }
                }
                catch (COMException comExc)
                {
                    // Handle any errors that might occur on NextFeature().
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(featureCursor);
                }

                // Flag the new selection
                m_focusMap.PartialRefresh(ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGeoSelection, null, null);
                #endregion

                // 5. If the cursor is no longer needed, release it.
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(featureCursor);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the [IEnvelope from the IActiveView.Extent](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Extent_Property/0012000001mz000000/). The envelope can be used as an input into the selection tools. Note:

> The Extent property holds the visible area of the view.  The Extent is
>   automatically captured whenever the view's transformation changes. 
>   For example, when the active view is a Map, the Extent is modified
>   whenever the spatial reference changes.  Also, the Extent is set the
>   first time a layer is added to a Map.  In layout view, the Extent is
>   initially set to the page size.  In both layout view and data view,
>   zooming in our out changes the Extent.  The Extent is always adjusted
>   to fit the device frame and it is persisted in the map document.

Comment: Does it matter if I use use mxDoc.FocusMap as IActiveView instead of mxDoc.ActiveView?

Comment: You can have multiple Map objects. When you call focus map it will use the one that was most recently added. If you're only working with one Map object you're fine to go with .FocusMap - if you have multiple Map objects you will have to be more careful when getting your extent.